# Manually manage transactions in Jpa Repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How can I manually manage the commit/rollback/close of the database transactions in a jpa repository.

Basically I want to have multiple connections in the same method at the same time and tell the repository which one to use and control when to commit or rollback the connection.

Comment: I am not sure it's possible using JPA API, you have to use `EntityManager` for these purposes

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions ...

Comment: Thanks @crizzis that helped me to implement my solution, can you post it as an answer?